# Use Jquery in KO Js Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

On checkout page i want to hide summary component by default. and when a user clicks on a button i to show that Summary section. The Summary section is build through XML and KO. My Question is, Can i use Jquery in KO?

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'jquery'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator,
    customer,
    $
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/check-login'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),
        isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
        //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
        stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
        //step title value
        stepTitle: 'Login',

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                this.stepCode,
                //step alias
                null,
                this.stepTitle,
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                9
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }

    });


        $(".checkout-btn").click(function(){
        console.log("Hello World");
            $(".order-summary-sec").css("display","block");
        });


}
);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container checkout-acc-container checkout-acc-container-2 ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 mr-auto ml-auto offset-lg-3">
        <h2>Checkout</h2>
        <div class="acc-fields-sec" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="field input-acc-field email-field">
            <p class="already-reg-text">This email is already registered with us, please sign in below</p>

            <label class="field-label password-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="field input-acc-field password-field">
            <p class="checkout-btn-sec">

                <a href="#" class="checkout-btn"><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></a>
            </p>
            <p class="or-with-fb-text">OR sign in with Facebook</p>
            <p class="fb-btn-sec">
                <a href="#" class="fb-btn"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

at the last i have pasted my jQuery Code. But it is not working.Any idea how i could be?

Comment: NO but you can add similar js into it then https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Comment: can you please add this example in my code and repost it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your jQuery in initialize function. However, I would not recommend writing jQuery in your viewModal as it creates coupling between your viewModal and DOM elements. Your final code would be something like following ;

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'jquery'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator,
    customer,
    $
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/check-login'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),
        isLogedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
        //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
        stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
        //step title value
        stepTitle: 'Login',

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                this.stepCode,
                //step alias
                null,
                this.stepTitle,
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                9
            );

            $(".checkout-btn").click(function(){
            console.log("Hello World");
                $(".order-summary-sec").css("display","block");
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: let me try this. if you dont recommend then can you share same this in KO Js?

Comment: Please share your html template if you want the same in KO.

Comment: added in question. please check.

Comment: Is the current jquery code I've provided working ?

Comment: no, it is not working. http://prntscr.com/n8zvok

Comment: you are trying to access DOM element with class order-summary-sec which is not in your template. KO can essentially work within the scope of its own template so it cannot be done using ko bindings.

Comment: Failed to load the "${$.component}" component.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **`jQuery function`** instead of **`$()`**
Examine this:

```
jQuery(".checkout-btn").click(function(){
        console.log("Hello World");
        jQuery(".order-summary-sec").css("display","block");
});
```

Can you try this:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function(jQuery) {
        jQuery(".checkout-btn").click(function () {
            console.log("Hello World");
            jQuery(".order-summary-sec").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not working at all.

Comment: I think you can go with injecting jQuery directly to your html

Comment: It is not the standard way but I think it is the easiest way to make it work.

Comment: i tried that, but in html the jquery never worked.

Comment: can you show me how you did it?

Comment: I mean your codes how did you insert it in html?

Comment: this is how i did this http://prntscr.com/n90ip1

Comment: @i_ali55 updated my answer, you can check

Comment: do i have to add this in html template?

Comment: yeah , just change the code you tried in your html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92138/discussion-between-i-ali55-and-magefms).